# How can I resolve 'Module not found' errors in a React application when deploying it on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, vercel

When I try to deploy my app on vercel I get 'Module not found:' errors. The program runs fine in local environment. But on Vercel it doesn't..

[image]

How do I fix these errors? I tried installing react packaged in terminal but it still give errors...